# index0errorValue must be a string - Upload multiple files Swagger .NET 6.0

Tags: asp.net, swagger, multiple-file-upload, iformfile

I declared a list IFormFile:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("test_file")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> test_file([FromForm] IEnumerable<IFormFile> lstFile)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

But swagger interpreted as a list of string and shows issue: "index0errorValue must be a string"(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uaP1.png)

Can you help to fix this problem?
Thanks a lot

**EDIT:**
I fixed the error.

```
app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
//options.SerializeAsV2 = true;
options.RouteTemplate = swaggerOption.JsonRoute;
});
```

SerializeAsV2. I don't know how it works, but when I turned it off, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Consume attribute for that matter. The [Consumes] attribute in ASP.NET Core is used to specify the content types that a controller action method can consume or accept from which swagger is going to detect automatically.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
[Route("test_file")]
public async Task<IActionResult> test_file([FromForm] IEnumerable<IFormFile> lstFile)
{
    // TODO: Apply the logic here 
    return null;
}
```

[For more information you can check the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.consumesattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your solution but the matter is still there.

Comment: maybe your swagger configuration is different. I double-checked with standard configurations and there are no problems with it. you can add your configuration settings by updating the question.

Comment: @Reza_Heidari The error is fixed. Thanks for the suggestion